# OAuth with yahoo finance

Tags: objective-c, ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, yahoo-finance

I'm developping an iPhone application and i'm trying to authenticate and authorize the user to connect to yahoo finance to view his portfolio.
Is it possible for me to authenticate a user using OAuth, then display the user's yahoo finance portfolio on a TableView?

Many thanks.

---

Is there any other service like google finance that I can use to display user's finance portfolio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that Yahoo Finance has any APIs that would allow you to retrieve a user's portfolio. The [last word I saw on the topic](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Retrieving-Portfolios-from-My-Yahoo-Finance/1237253160000-61f8d0f3-9923-3551-ba9c-929caa212016) was from a few years ago and said: "As far as I know there are no plans to release a Finance API." Also, the [Yahoo APIs page](http://developer.yahoo.com/everything.html) does not list any Finance APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Is there any other service like google finance that I can use to display user's finance portfolio?

Comment: None that I know of. Google has one that they are shutting down in October. I don't think Bing has one. Intuit has portfolios, but no APIs.